# The table associated with app\models\Post must have primary key(s)

Tags: php, yii

В /gii/crud  когда добавляю crud пишет 'The table associated with app\models\Post must have primary key(s).'  что мне сделат ?﻿

[image: Бот снимок]

Comment: вероятно, на предыдущем шаге при создании модели (`Category`?) требовалось указать поле первичного ключа

Comment: видимо таблица БД создается отдельно и самостоятельно, поэтому создайте первичный ключ в таблице теми инструментами,которые вы использовали для создания самой таблицы

Comment: Да это я понял но не знаю как это сделать. Поможет мне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если ваша таблица называется "category" то зайдите в базу данных  любым удобным для вас способом (comand line, phpmyadmin etc.) и выполните sql запрос

```
ALTER TABLE `category` ADD `id_pk` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_pk`);
```